# centos vagrant boxes are invoking init script every instance on vagrant up command

Tags: vagrant, vagrant-provision

I'm having centos vagrant box. Code can be found [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/VBoxes/tree/master/hadoop-learnbyexample/stand-alone).

On each instance when I do `vagrant up`, the shell script for provisioning is invoked.

This is not the case when I have ubuntu based vagrant box. Ubuntu box provisions only when I do `vagrant reload` not on `vagrant up` command.

How can I avoid invoking provision shell script every time on `vagrant up` without changing the file or vagrant OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Vagrant file you setup

```
config.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", path: "standalone.sh"
```

run: "always"

In this case provision will not be invoked only if you run

```
vagrant up --no-provision
```

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/up.html#no-provision